# Spiegelbildliches Gegenstück zu Futur II?

Tags: tense, curiosity, past, future

Das Futur II beschreibt den Blick auf etwas zukünftiges aus Sicht eines noch späteren Zeitpunktes. Gibt es ein spiegelbildliches Analogon, mit dem man den Blick auf etwas vergangenes aus Sicht eines noch früheren Zeitpunktes beschreiben kann?

Als konkretes Beispiel mal eine Silvesterfeier:

- Vom 30.12. aus gesehen:

> - Blick auf den 31.12.: Morgen wird die Feier stattfinden (Futur)
> - Blick auf den 1.1.: Übermorgen wird die Feier stattgefunden haben (Futur II)

- Vom 1.1. aus gesehen:

> - Blick auf den 31.12.: Gestern hat die Feier stattgefunden / fand die Feier statt (Perfekt/Imperfekt)
> - Blick auf den 30.12.: Vorgestern ???

Gibt es eine Möglichkeit, den Umstand, dass die Feier vorgestern noch in der Zukunft lag, analog zur obigen Systematik in einer aktiven Formulierung mit einer Variation von *stattfinden werden* zu beschreiben?

Edit:

Danke für die Antwortversuche, ich hatte schon damit gerechnet, dass die Antwort "nein" lauten würde. Hintergrund der Frage waren humorvoll gemeinte Versuche (von 2 verschiedenen Freunden bei unterschiedlichen Gelegenheiten), für eine Veranstaltung, zu der man aus Planungsgründen sein Kommen ankündigen sollte, dies nach der Veranstaltung rückwirkend zu tun, was in beiden Fällen zu grammatikalisch eher verkorksten Sätzen führte, und ich wollte gern wissen, ob dies überhaupt möglich sei, hatte aber wie gesagt mit einem nein gerechnet.

Comment: "Das Futur II beschreibt den Blick auf etwas zukünftiges aus Sicht eines noch späteren Zeitpunktes." - Das ist übrigens nicht richtig. Siehe das "berühmte" Gegenbeispiel aus der IDS-Grammatik: A bezahlt B monatlich für ein auf ein Jahr angelegtes Projekt. Unerwartet hat B das Projekt gestern nach nur 6 Monaten fertiggestellt. Heute fragt A bei B nach dem Stand. B, der gerne weiter Geld erhalten möchte, sagt: _Ich werde das Projekt zum vereinbarten Zeitpunkt fertiggestellt haben._ Diese Aussage ist wahr. Wie man daran sieht, muss das Ereignis im Futur II nicht zukünftig sein.

Answer (score 4):

Die folgenden Konstrukte kommen dem wohl am nächsten.

> Er hatte am 30.12 Geburtstag. Am folgenden Tag würde er auch noch Silvester feiern.
>
> Er hatte am 30.12 Geburtstag. Ein Woche später würde er auch noch Silvester gefeiert haben.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt mehrere Möglichkeiten. Alle haben den Gebrauch des Plusquamperfekts gemein.

Implizit:

> Sie hatte geplant, um 10 Uhr am Bahnhof zu sein.

Mit dem Konjunktiv II von werden:

> Sie hatte angenommen, dass der Fußgänger die Straße überqueren würde.

Mit Modalverb im Präteritum:

> Er hatte frühzeitig erkannt, dass dieser Plan scheitern musste.

Comment: Und leider haben auch alle gemein, dass sie eben nicht der Systematik meiner drei Beispiele folgen, sondern jeweils einen Nebensatz benötigen.

Comment: Ohne den Nebensatz hast du keine zweite Möglichkeit zu konjugieren. Dann brauchst du wie in deinen Beispielen auch irgendwelche anderen Zeitmarkierungen. Im Futur II steckt das nämlich auch nicht drin.

Answer (score -1):

Es gibt dazu kein grammatikalisches Analog zum Futurum Exactum, man kann aber sagen:

> Vorgestern wird die Feier (erst/noch/am nächsten Tag/bald...) stattfinden.

Wobei wohl ein Attribut wie "am Folgetag" etc. eingefügt werden muss, um für Klarheit zu sorgen.

Also das Futur I ist hier angebracht.

Beispiel im Dialog:

> A: "Hast du mir vorgestern die Fotos von der Feier geschickt?"
>
> B: "Nein, vorgestern wird die Party erst stattfinden."

statt

> B: "Nein, vorgestern hatte die Feier noch nicht stattgefunden."

Comment: Ich würde keine Angabe in der Vergangenheit "vorgestern" mit Zukunftsformen ("wird stattfinden") kombinieren, das klingt für mich falsch. Hier würde ich "hatte noch nicht stattgefunden" verwenden.